# parsing sizes from textual data

Tags: parsing, nlp, text-parsing

I want to extract sizes , from textual data ("the missile was fifty five inches long." , or "he weighted nine and a half pounds.") and convert them to data in a format usable by a program.

What's a good way to go about this ? 
Are there any helpful libraries ?

And how complex is this task ?

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this as an information extraction (IE) problem. In that case, the basic approach is formulate a bunch of regular expressions that describe the problem approximately and refine those until they're either good enough or you can't get any further.

Or, you could *your favorite parser* and see what kind of trees/dependency structures it produces for the sentences you're after, figure out the general pattern, check how well it does and maybe filter the results with a regexp or some predicate on the returned structure.